# Drupal 7 drop down menu not showing on other pages

Tags: routes, navigation

I have the main menu with 4 links (home, services, portfolio, contact)

under "services" I created a sub-menu, (service1, service2, service3)

The problem is that the little arrow that drops down the sub-menu shows ONLY on the "services" page and NOT the other pages.

How to fix that? thanks.

Comment: did you check `Show as expanded` for the other menus? also did you try to change your custom theme to another core drupal themes to see if you have the same issue?

Comment: what was the issue? can you post your answer?

Answer (score 4):

To clarify:

1. Go to Structure/Menus;
2. Select the menu with the non-expanding menu item (ie. Main menu);
3. Select the List Links tab if not already;
4. Click the "edit" link for the non-expanding menu item - the "Show as expanded" button is there.

Answer (score 0):

This just shows them expanded all the time. Not very 'internet standard'.... how about getting them to show on hover as is the basic? Do we HAVE to use modules, variables, template tweaks??? Can't Drupal provide arguably the most important part of a website without going though a bunch of hoops?